# How to connect Google Analytics in a Flutter Web App?

Tags: flutter, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, flutter-web

I'm trying to use the [Google API Package (Pub Dev)](https://pub.dev/packages/googleapis) but with no lucky to undestand how to connect it in my Flutter Project.

Answer (score 0):

Hi  you need to use this package https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_analytics

you can find a sample App using analytics following [this link](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/tree/master/packages/firebase_analytics/firebase_analytics/example)

Google Analytics works on mobile Apps too and provides all sorts of useful features check this link [for more info](https://firebase.google.com/products/analytics?gclid=Cj0KCQjw_8mHBhClARIsABfFgphhQTdYKDNQGsoClmra5QgGB_HlECN60vdXVevMWxIfkoucQ4x8PyUaAp0GEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Firebase Analytics is available for mobile apps only right?

Comment: @BrunoNeuman Yes it works on iOS & Android apps - i added all the links you'll need  in the post 

Comment: FYI you need to have your app linked to Firebase but i think you got that

Comment: Actually, there is a package for web that you should definitely use instead of the mobile one: https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_analytics_web

Answer (score 0):

You need to add dependency for analytics in `android/app/build.gradle`, `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'`. If you need to log events then you might want to use the package https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_analytics. Otherwise just adding above dependency is sufficient.

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for a simple approach more than using a package, then you can follow the below solution.

Add the following `app.js` in `web/` directory

```js
// file: /web/app.js
function sendNavigation(location) {
    // Replace UA-XXXXXXXXX-X with Google Analytics ID
    gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXXX-X', { page_path: location });
}
```

Add the script into `web/index.html` by adding

```html
<head>
  <!--...-->
  <script src="app.js" defer></script>
</head>
```

Now, you can simply call

```dart
js.context.callMethod('sendNavigation', ['routePath']);
```

when the user navigates to the page in dart file.

You can learn more about this from a blog I wrote - [link](https://medium.com/@immadisairaj/google-analytics-with-flutter-web-c6d35664e569)